# Split channel entry data into rows / columns with stash

Tags: stash, switch

With Stash, is it possible to store pieces of EE channel entry data and insert it based on a count or some other logic?

I have a three column bootstrap grid below that splits an entry's data into two parts in the template.

Can I store and get the data based on a count or some other logic using Stash and Switch?

```
.row
- col {entry 1}
- col {entry 2}
- col {entry 3}

.row-two
- col {entry 1 data}
.row-two
- col {entry 2 data}
.row-two
- col {entry 3 data}

.row
- col {entry 4}
- col {entry 5}
- col {entry 6}

.row-two
- col {entry 4 data}
.row-two
- col {entry 5 data}
.row-two
- col {entry 6 data}

-etc-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the entries as a Stash list and use fractions to split into parts:

**Setting the list:**
https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset_list%7D#capturing-channel-entry-data

**Getting the list and using fractions:**
https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D#using-fractions-to-split-lists

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks! I have it set up pretty much exactly how I need it, just struggling with exact fractions/offsets. I'm outputting 16 entries and grouping them in 3s, which works until the 5th loop: Code: pastebin.com/XRe6WT8b It's a bit messy, but I'm planning on saving the get list markup as stash variables so that I'm not repeating those code blocks.

Comment: So I ended up just setting the offsets without fractions and everything works great. Thanks again!